# Char to Int in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, data-structures

I have a column in my database with the name: product_no and its data type is char(25)

i want to be able to search the name of the products by simply typing product_no in the search box and retrieve the result.

I am trying the code below but it doesnt work.
When i replace product_no with some other columns in my database whose data types are int, the code below works.

I suspect that this code doesnt work because product_no is not int. Any ideas?

```
public string getproductdetail(int ID)
{
    Product prod = new Product();
    string connectionString =
      "server=server;uid=user;pwd=pwd;database=DB;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = "Select name from dbo.product(nolock) Where product_no = " + ID.ToString();
        connection.Open();
  SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            prod.name          = reader["name"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
[DataContract]
public class Product
{
[DataMember]
public string name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for it until you are using `=` operator **but** if your want to use `between`, `>`, `<` etc. then you should convert that `Char` to an `Int` datatype. Other than that if you want to order the records in that column than too you should convert it.

To convert datatype of values in an SQL query you can try this

```
string sql = 
    "Select name from dbo.product(nolock) Where CONVERT(int, product_no) = @product_no";
```

for a proper documentation visit [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

Comment: @ŞenolŞahin your question isn't clear to me, Are you asking about how to change the datatype of a column in SQL or how to convert the datatype of a value in SQL ?

Answer (score 1):

If product_no is not an int type you should use ' characters in the query to enter the parameter. I recommend to use SqlParameter

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string sql = "Select name from dbo.product(nolock) Where product_no = @product_no";
        connection.Open();
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@product_no", ID);
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            prod.name = reader["name"].ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: SqlParameter is the generic way to introduce a parameter in the query. If you want to do it without SqlParameter you can try modifying the query to `Where product_no = '" + ID.ToString() + "'` or better `Where product_no LIKE '" + ID.ToString() + "'`. You can also change the column type with `Where CONVERT(int, product_no) = " + ID.ToString() `

Comment: No idea, this seems like a communications error. Have you tryed to run the query in the SQL Server management studio?

Answer (score 1):

TRy Like This:

```
public string getproductdetail(int ID)
    {
        Product prod = new Product();
    String product_no=Convert.ToString(Id);
        string connectionString =
          "server=server;uid=user;pwd=pwd;database=DB;";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            string sql = "Select name from dbo.product(nolock) Where product_no = " + product_no.ToString();
            connection.Open();
      SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                prod.name          = reader["name"].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    }
    [DataContract]
    public class Product
    {
    [DataMember]
    public string name;
    }
```